# What does the N7 Warfare Gear DLC do?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When I got the game I got the N7 Warfare Gear DLC, I've installed it, but I have no idea what it does, apparently it adds 'Argus 55 Rifle, plus additional content'. Where do I get this rifle or do I start with it, and what's the additional content it's talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the following with the DLC:

- [N7 Defender Armour](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/N7_Defender_Armor)
- [N7 Valkyrie Assault Rifle](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/N7_Valkyrie)
- [M-55 Argus Assault Rifle](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/M-55_Argus)

The weapons are available at the weapons bench, which is available at the shuttle bay of the Normandy.

[image]

[image]

The armor is available in your Cabin and in the Shutle Bay, where you can select amongst the various casual and armor outfits.

[image]

Comment: You can also change armor in the Cargo Bay, same floor as the weapons bench

Comment: @BenBrocka yep, updating.. upload speeds are slow ;)